# How to display multi-column article from a single column article data source?

Tags: javascript, css

How is the cleanest way to create a multi-column article from a single article source? So the article source is just one long article with no cutting information whatsoever. The web page then read it from the database, and then display it in "multi-column with equal height" format, like in a newspaper, or like in Microsoft Word. The catch is I need to do this as cleanest as possible, and I need to be able to change how many column whenever I (or the user) want, without change the article data source at all. Is there an easy way to do this in javascript and css? I know how to create the divs, but to specify where to cut the article or how many lines to count, it's just beyond my current understanding of javascript. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest and easiest way is by using [`column-count`](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/).

```
div {
    -webkit-column-count:3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
    column-count:3;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/WxNZ6/).

Do note that it isn't supported in all (older) browsers, check the first link to see the support!

Comment: oh! then I only need to use one div then? no need to create a div for each column?

Comment: No, no need for that!  But like said, mind the browser support!

Answer (score 1):

Using it with media query for responsiveness

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/vy43K/3/)**

css

```
article p {
    -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #ccc;
    column-rule: 1px solid #ccc;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
    column-gap: 1.5em;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  article p {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;      
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a little too advanced, but I might need it someday. I've seen the demo and I think it's a very neat trick! Thank you very much. :)